# How to remove outliers efficiently for each trial

Tags: r, performance, loops, dataframe

I'm new to R so all I know is how to write for loops but I definitely think there is a more efficient way to do what I am trying to do.

Here's the code I have now:

```
for (i in 1:length(unique(poo$TRIAL_INDEX))) {
zz <- subset(poo, TRIAL_INDEX==i)
sds <- sd(zz$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE, na.rm = TRUE)
avgpupil <- mean(zz$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE, na.rm = TRUE)
#what im trying to do in the lines above is subset the data for every trial 
#so that I can calculate the standard deviation and average for each trial
for (j in 1:length(zz$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE)) {
if (zz$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE[j] > 3*sds+avgpupil | zz$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE[j] < avgpupil-3*sds | is.na(zz$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE[j])) {
  zz$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE[j]  <- NA_character_
  goo <- rbind(zz[j],goo)
} else {
  goo <- rbind(zz[j],goo)
}
}
}
#then I want it to replace the value in RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE with NA if it is 
# 3 SD above or under the mean, and if it's NA. Then I bind it to a new dataframe
```

My computer cannot handle this code. 
Any suggestion is welcomed!

Comment: can you give us a sample of your `poo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might do most of what you want.  I did not understand the `rbind` part of your question:

```
poo <- read.table(text = '
     TRIAL_INDEX     RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE
          1                 10
          1                  8
          1                  6
          1                  4
          1                 NA
          2                  1
          2                  2
          2                 NA
          2                  4
          2                  5
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "NA")


my.summary <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", tapply(poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE, poo$TRIAL_INDEX, 
    function(x) c(index.sd = sd(x, na.rm = TRUE), index.mean = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)))))

my.summary$TRIAL_INDEX <- rownames(my.summary)

poo <- merge(poo, my.summary, by = 'TRIAL_INDEX')

poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE <- ifelse( (poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE > (poo$index.mean + 3 * poo$index.sd)) | 
                                (poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE < (poo$index.mean - 3 * poo$index.sd)) | 
                                is.na(poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE),  NA, poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE)

poo

#   TRIAL_INDEX RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE index.sd index.mean
#1            1               10 2.581989          7
#2            1                8 2.581989          7
#3            1                6 2.581989          7
#4            1                4 2.581989          7
#5            1               NA 2.581989          7
#6            2                1 1.825742          3
#7            2                2 1.825742          3
#8            2               NA 1.825742          3
#9            2                4 1.825742          3
#10           2                5 1.825742          3
```

Here is a solution using `aggregate`:

```
my.summary <- with(poo, aggregate(RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE, by = list(TRIAL_INDEX), 
                   FUN = function(x) { c(index.sd = sd(x, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                         index.mean = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)) } ))

my.summary <- do.call(data.frame, my.summary)

colnames(my.summary) <- c('TRIAL_INDEX', 'index.sd', 'index.mean')

poo <- merge(poo, my.summary, by = 'TRIAL_INDEX')

poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE <- ifelse((poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE > (poo$index.mean + 3 * poo$index.sd)) | 
                               (poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE < (poo$index.mean - 3 * poo$index.sd)) | 
                               is.na(poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE),  NA, poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE)
```

Here is a solution using `ave`:

```
index.mean <- ave(poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE, poo$TRIAL_INDEX, FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))
index.sd   <- ave(poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE, poo$TRIAL_INDEX, FUN = function(x)   sd(x, na.rm = TRUE))

poo <- data.frame(poo, index.mean, index.sd)

poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE <- ifelse((poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE > (poo$index.mean + 3 * poo$index.sd)) | 
                               (poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE < (poo$index.mean - 3 * poo$index.sd)) | 
                               is.na(poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE),  NA, poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE)
```

Here is a solution using `dplyr` that differs a little from the `dplyr` solution by Dave2e.  His is probably better, as I have never used `dplyr` until posting this answer.

```
library(dplyr)
my.summary <- poo %>%
    group_by(TRIAL_INDEX) %>% 
    summarise(index.mean = mean(RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE, na.rm = TRUE), 
                index.sd =   sd(RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE, na.rm = TRUE))

my.summary

poo <- merge(poo, as.data.frame(my.summary), by = 'TRIAL_INDEX')


poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE <- ifelse((poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE > (poo$index.mean + 3 * poo$index.sd)) | 
                               (poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE < (poo$index.mean - 3 * poo$index.sd)) | 
                               is.na(poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE),  NA, poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE)

poo
```

Here is a solution using `data.table`.  There are probably better solutions using `data.table`.  I think I only used `data.table` once before posting this answer.

```
poo <- read.table(text = '
     TRIAL_INDEX     RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE
          1                 10
          1                  8
          1                  6
          1                  4
          1                 NA
          2                  1
          2                  2
          2                 NA
          2                  4
          2                  5
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "NA")

library(data.table)

my.summary <- data.frame(setDT(poo)[, .(index.mean = mean(RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                          index.sd =   sd(RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE, na.rm = TRUE)),
                     .(TRIAL_INDEX)])

poo <- merge(poo, my.summary, by = 'TRIAL_INDEX')

poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE <- ifelse((poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE > (poo$index.mean + 3 * poo$index.sd)) | 
                               (poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE < (poo$index.mean - 3 * poo$index.sd)) | 
                               is.na(poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE),  NA, poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE)

poo
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample data:

```
#dput(poo)
poo<-structure(list(TRIAL_INDEX = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE = c(10.2043651385866, 
20.9885863196198, NA, 199, 8.83696635172232, 18.7815785751864, 
10.3610991868418, 19.6540748580446, 8.5323332390802, 20.2930866405183, 
8.74706048647041, 17.6785303413612, 10.0699206520888, 21.359973619746, 
10.1517982308973, 18.7513452694493, 8.44732655940166, 20.5369556689887, 
8.63612148828901, 22.2712027851507)), .Names = c("TRIAL_INDEX", 
"RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Using the dplyr package to group and by Trial index and then mutate on the Z score created by the scale function:

```
library(dplyr)
poo<-mutate(group_by(poo, TRIAL_INDEX), z=as.numeric(scale(RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE)))

poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE[abs(poo$z)>2]<-NA
```

The as.numeric function is required to simplify the result from the scale function to a simple vector.