# microbenchmark with datatable, tapply, aggregate, ave and dplyr

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate, dplyr, tapply

I was attempting to compare speed of several approaches for obtaining summary statistics by group.  However, I am get an error when running `microbenchmark`.  The error states:

```
Error in bmerge(i, x, leftcols, rightcols, io, xo, roll, rollends, nomatch,  : 
  x.'TRIAL_INDEX' is a character column being joined to i.'TRIAL_INDEX' which is type 'integer'. Character columns must join to factor or character columns.
```

I am not sure, but I think `data.table` changes an `attribute` of the variable `TRIAL_INDEX`.  From searching `Stack Overflow` for similar questions, I guess there have been conflicts between some packages.

Is there a work-around, so I can perhaps change the attribute of `TRIAL_INDEX` back to `integer` or take other action so the `microbenchmark` function will work?  Or maybe I am making an error I am not seeing.

Here is the code with the five functions I am attempting to compare.  From running subsets of these functions I am impressed by how fast the `ave` function is.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

poo <- read.table(text = '
     TRIAL_INDEX     RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE
          1                 10
          1                  8
          1                  6
          1                  4
          1                 NA
          2                  1
          2                  2
          2                 NA
          2                  4
          2                  5
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "NA")

tapply.function <- function(x) {

     my.summary <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", 
                   tapply(poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE, poo$TRIAL_INDEX, 
                   function(x) c(index.mean = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE),
                                   index.sd =   sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)))))

     my.summary$TRIAL_INDEX <- rownames(my.summary)

     poo2 <- merge(poo, my.summary, by = 'TRIAL_INDEX')

     return(poo2)

}

str(tapply.function(poo))

aggregate.function <- function(x) {

     my.summary <- with(poo, aggregate(RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE, by = list(TRIAL_INDEX), 
                        FUN = function(x) {c( index.mean = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                              index.sd   =   sd(x, na.rm = TRUE))}))

     my.summary <- do.call(data.frame, my.summary)

     colnames(my.summary) <- c('TRIAL_INDEX', 'index.mean', 'index.sd')

     poo2 <- merge(poo, my.summary, by = 'TRIAL_INDEX')

     return(poo2)

}

str(aggregate.function(poo))

ave.function <- function(x) {

     index.mean <- ave(poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE, poo$TRIAL_INDEX, FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))
     index.sd   <- ave(poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE, poo$TRIAL_INDEX, FUN = function(x)   sd(x, na.rm = TRUE))

     poo2 <- data.frame(poo, index.mean, index.sd)

     return(poo2)

}

str(ave.function(poo))

dplyr.function <- function(x) {

     my.summary <- poo %>%
         group_by(TRIAL_INDEX) %>% 
         summarise(index.mean = mean(RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE, na.rm = TRUE),
                     index.sd =   sd(RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE, na.rm = TRUE))

     poo2 <- merge(poo, as.data.frame(my.summary), by = 'TRIAL_INDEX')

     return(poo2)

}

str(dplyr.function(poo))

data.table.function <- function(x) {

     my.summary <- data.frame(setDT(poo)[, .(index.mean = mean(RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                               index.sd =   sd(RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE, na.rm = TRUE)),
                          .(TRIAL_INDEX)])

     poo2 <- merge(poo, my.summary, by = 'TRIAL_INDEX')

     return(poo2)

}

str(data.table.function(poo))

# this does not work
microbenchmark(    tapply.function(poo),
                aggregate.function(poo),
                      ave.function(poo),
                    dplyr.function(poo), 
               data.table.function(poo), times = 1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple test you could've done is to add a `cat("In tapply")`, `cat("In ave")` etc.. to your functions and run it again with `times = 1L` to debug.

Doing that, I get this:

```
> microbenchmark(    tapply.function(poo),
+                    aggregate.function(poo),
+                    ave.function(poo),
+                    dplyr.function(poo), 
+                    data.table.function(poo), times = 1)
In dplyr
In tapply
Error in bmerge(i, x, leftcols, rightcols, io, xo, roll, rollends, nomatch,  : 
  x.'TRIAL_INDEX' is a character column being joined to i.'TRIAL_INDEX' which is type 'integer'. Character columns must join to factor or character columns.
```

The error happens at `tapply` function.

Let's have a look at the first two lines in that function:

```
my.summary <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", tapply(poo$RIGHT_PUPIL_SIZE, 
                  poo$TRIAL_INDEX, function(x) c(index.mean = mean(x, na.rm = 
                        TRUE), index.sd =   sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)))))
my.summary$TRIAL_INDEX <- rownames(my.summary)
```

ding ding ding.. we've a winner...

```
str(my.summary)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ index.mean : num  7 3
#  $ index.sd   : num  2.58 1.83
#  $ TRIAL_INDEX: chr  "1" "2" ## <~~~ char type
```

And that's the reason for the error message on the next `merge`. Why? Because you're using `setDT(poo)` (weird name for an object btw) in `data.table.function()` that modifies `poo` (?!?) *by reference*. And all subsequent tests use that object as a data.table.

At the end of your `data.table.function()`, before returning the ans, use `setDF(poo)`, or use `as.data.table(poo)` in that function instead, and benchmark the time for `as.data.table(poo)` separately so that we can deduct the time for conversion from the timing of data.table function.

All of this aside, on 10 rows, you're very likely to just measure the overhead in type conversion from data.frame -> data.table -> data.frame. I'm not sure what meaningful conclusions you can get from ns/us timings (unless you're repeating this task >1,000 or 10,000 times).

Comment: Thank you.  I will try to implement your suggestions.  I did use `str(tapply.function(poo))` which seemed to say `TRIAL_INDEX` was integer.  But that was the limit of my understanding.  I agree that `poo` is an unusual name.  It comes from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623544/how-to-remove-outliers-efficiently-for-each-trial/37624320#37624320 and I did not change it.

Comment: No worries. `tapply()` function would work fine on data.frames because base R's merge doesn't warn/error about different types. But data.table's merge does.. (and I think it's better to). When data.table.function() has been run once, then it'd start to fail. Microbenchmark shuffles/samples functions before benchmarking, and I guess I was lucky with `times=1L`. Perhaps `times=2L` is more appropriate.